# Discord.js: how can I make paticular permissons for each reaction?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

I am coding a `!ticket` command and cannot handle allowing members without any permissions to react ⛔.

**Code**

```
module.exports = {
  name: "ticket",
  slash: true,
  aliases: [],
  permissions: [],
  description: "open a ticket!",
  async execute(client, message, args) {
    let chanel = message.guild.channels.cache.find(c => c.name === `ticket-${(message.author.username).toLowerCase()}`);
    if (chanel) return message.channel.send('You already have a ticket open.');
    const channel = await message.guild.channels.create(`ticket-${message.author.username}`)
    
    channel.setParent("837065612546539531");

    channel.updateOverwrite(message.guild.id, {
      SEND_MESSAGE: false,
      VIEW_CHANNEL: false,
    });
    channel.updateOverwrite(message.author, {
      SEND_MESSAGE: true,
      VIEW_CHANNEL: true,
    });

    const reactionMessage = await channel.send(`${message.author}, welcome to your ticket!\nHere you can:\n:one: Report an issue or bug of the server.\n:two: Suggest any idea for the server.\n:three: Report a staff member of the server.\n\nMake sure to be patient, support will be with you shortly.\n<@&837064899322052628>`)

    try {
      await reactionMessage.react("");
      await reactionMessage.react("⛔");
    } catch (err) {
      channel.send("Error sending emojis!");
      throw err;
    }

    const collector = reactionMessage.createReactionCollector(
      (reaction, user) => message.guild.members.cache.find((member) => member.id === user.id).hasPermission("ADMINISTRATOR"),
      { dispose: true }
    );

    collector.on("collect", (reaction, user) => {
      switch (reaction.emoji.name) {
        case "":
          channel.updateOverwrite(message.author, { SEND_MESSAGES: false });
          break;
        case "⛔":
          channel.send("Deleting this ticket in 5 seconds...");
          setTimeout(() => channel.delete(), 5000);
          break;
      }
    });

    message.channel
      .send(`We will be right with you! ${channel}`)
      .then((msg) => {
        setTimeout(() => msg.delete(), 7000);
        setTimeout(() => message.delete(), 3000);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        throw err;
      });
  },
};
```

It is related to the following part of the code.

```
const collector = reactionMessage.createReactionCollector(
      (reaction, user) => message.guild.members.cache.find((member) => member.id === user.id).hasPermission("ADMINISTRATOR"),
      { dispose: true }
    );
```

I want it to allow lock the ticket for administrators, and allow to close for everyone.

Comment: So you would like the  ⛔ reaction to only be used by users with a certain permission level? Edit just saw bottom of post

Comment: @FAXES okay, lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I understand you correctly, but it seems you have two reactions and only want admins to use the , and both admins and the original author to use the `⛔`.

Your current code only collects reactions from members who have `ADMINISTRATOR` permissions. You should change the filter to also collect reactions from the member who created the ticket.

The following filter does exactly that.

```js
const filter = (reaction, user) => {
  const isOriginalAuthor = message.author.id === user.id;
  const isAdmin = message.guild.members.cache
    .find((member) => member.id === user.id)
    .hasPermission('ADMINISTRATOR');

  return isOriginalAuthor || isAdmin;
}
```

There are other errors in your code, like there is no `SEND_MESSAGE` flag, only `SEND_MESSAGES`. You should also use more try-catch blocks to catch any errors.

It's also a good idea to explicitly allow the bot to send messages in the newly created channel. I use [`overwritePermissions`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=overwritePermissions) instead of `updateOverwrite`. It allows you to use an array of overwrites, so you can update it with a single method.

To solve the issue with the lock emoji... I check the permissions of the member who reacted with a , and if it has no `ADMINISTRATOR`, I simply delete their reaction using [`reaction.users.remove(user)`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ReactionUserManager?scrollTo=remove).

Check out the working code below:

```js
module.exports = {
  name: 'ticket',
  slash: true,
  aliases: [],
  permissions: [],
  description: 'open a ticket!',
  async execute(client, message, args) {
    const username = message.author.username.toLowerCase();
    const parentChannel = '837065612546539531';
    const ticketChannel = message.guild.channels.cache.find((ch) => ch.name === `ticket-${username}`);
    if (ticketChannel)
      return message.channel.send(`You already have a ticket open: ${ticketChannel}`);

    let channel = null;
    try {
      channel = await message.guild.channels.create(`ticket-${username}`);

      await channel.setParent(parentChannel);
      await channel.overwritePermissions([
        // disable access to everyone
        {
          id: message.guild.id,
          deny: ['SEND_MESSAGES', 'VIEW_CHANNEL'],
        },
        // allow access for the one opening the ticket
        {
          id: message.author.id,
          allow: ['SEND_MESSAGES', 'VIEW_CHANNEL'],
        },
        // make sure the bot can also send messages
        {
          id: client.user.id,
          allow: ['SEND_MESSAGES', 'VIEW_CHANNEL'],
        },
      ]);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      return message.channel.send('⚠️ Error creating ticket channel!');
    }

    let reactionMessage = null;
    try {
      reactionMessage = await channel.send(
        `${message.author}, welcome to your ticket!\nHere you can:\n:one: Report an issue or bug of the server.\n:two: Suggest any idea for the server.\n:three: Report a staff member of the server.\n\nMake sure to be patient, support will be with you shortly.\n<@&837064899322052628>`,
      );
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      return message.channel.send(
        '⚠️ Error sending message in ticket channel!',
      );
    }

    try {
      await reactionMessage.react('');
      await reactionMessage.react('⛔');
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
      return channel.send('⚠️ Error sending emojis!');
    }

    const collector = reactionMessage.createReactionCollector(
      (reaction, user) => {
        // collect only reactions from the original
        // author and users w/ admin permissions
        const isOriginalAuthor = message.author.id === user.id;
        const isAdmin = message.guild.members.cache
          .find((member) => member.id === user.id)
          .hasPermission('ADMINISTRATOR');

        return isOriginalAuthor || isAdmin;
      },
      { dispose: true },
    );

    collector.on('collect', (reaction, user) => {
      switch (reaction.emoji.name) {
        // lock: admins only
        case '':
          const isAdmin = message.guild.members.cache
            .find((member) => member.id === user.id)
            .hasPermission('ADMINISTRATOR');

          if (isAdmin) {
            channel.updateOverwrite(message.author, {
              SEND_MESSAGES: false,
            });
          } else {
            // if not an admin, just remove the reaction
            // like nothing's happened
            reaction.users.remove(user);
          }
          break;
        // close: anyone i.e. any admin and the member
        // created the ticket
        case '⛔':
          channel.send('Deleting this ticket in 5 seconds...');
          setTimeout(() => channel.delete(), 5000);
          break;
      }
    });

    try {
      const msg = await message.channel.send(`We will be right with you! ${channel}`);
      setTimeout(() => msg.delete(), 7000);
      setTimeout(() => message.delete(), 3000);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  },
};
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: thank you for such a detailed answer, even with examples of work, you are awesome!